# Why is Safari on my computer rendering all of the colors -- not just for images -- incorrectly?

Tags: macos, mac, browser, safari

I’m not just talking about image color profile issues; every single color that the browser renders is incorrect. It’s like it’s in it’s own color space (or something!).

Screenshot: http://drp.ly/DJk1O (Opera, Safari, Chrome, Firefox)

Spot the odd one out? Open this up in Photoshop or similar and try using the eyedropper to select the colour. Safari renders the same hex color completely differently. That color is set using a background-color declaration in CSS, so it should be identical in all four of those browsers.

Here’s the HTML I was using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>untitled</title>

    <style type="text/css">
      body { background-color: #114742; }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Literally every website I’m viewing with my install of Safari is displaying colors incorrectly. The blue of the bar on Facebook is slightly less rich.

This doesn’t occur on any other Macs I’ve tried. Any idea what’s happened to my Safari install?

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that you have a bad display profile.

Answer (score 0):

Safari is correctly obeying the color profile you have set in your display preferences. Whereas the other browsers just ignore any color profile.

Check your  > System Preferences… > Displays > [Color] for which Color Profile you have activated.

Personal opinion: It does not have to be the 100% exact same color across different browsers, it is absolutely fine that it is coherent within the same browser. Normal users don't switch browsers every 5 minutes and compare sites across different browsers. They use one, and most of them use that one exclusively.

I haven't found a way to enable the correct use of ColorSync profiles in Firefox. I don't use Chrome/ium or Opera, so I can't check there.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to diagnose my own issue. It's essentially to do with a bug in this:

http://webkit.org/blog/73/color-spaces/

The best way to resolve it is to delete your ~/Library/Safari/ files and allow the browser to recreate them on next launch.